# How do I display only the current directory while using powerline in the terminal prompt.?

Tags: shell, prompt

Recently I installed the Powerline in the linux to enhance the look and feel of my terminal. It works great, however, it display 3 levels of directories in the prompt while traversing. Consider below example

```
unikx> ...>Dir1>Dir2>Dir3
```

where unikx is my username and Dir3 is my current working directory. The problem is, I have a habit of giving long names to directories. So due to above behaviour of Powerline showing 3 levels, I dont have enough space on that current line to write my commands and eventually my commands appear in the next line which I dont like.

So how do I customize powerline to show only 2 or current dir in the prompt like below:

```
unikx> ...>Dir3
```

or

```
unikx> ...>Dir2>Dir3
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think the setting you're looking for is in something like

```
<powerline_install_dir>/config_files/themes/shell/__main__.json
```

on this line:

```
"dir_limit_depth": 3
```

(Note that your installation may be different from mine so you might have to search for the file.)

See Powerline [quick setup guide](https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#quick-setup-guide). This [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/powerline/comments/3o1qlf/tips_and_tricks_trim_directory_names_for_long/) might also help. (If you're in a hurry edit that file directly.)

FYI, a simple alternative is the powerline command's `--width` flag which takes max width of the prompt in columns/characters. E.g. `powerline --width 40 ...`. This will dynamically resize segments of the prompt as needed which usually means shrinking the path segment.

You probably won't know if you like it until you try it. That way you can see exactly how it behaves for different console widths, different paths, with whatever other segments you are displaying, etc.

I couldn't find a straightforward way to set this but looking at the code it seems that setting `COLUMNS=X` (X is desired width) in your environment before invoking the `powerline.sh` startup script will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Before I try, I just want to know that after executing the powerline --width 40, what should i do to revert back incase i dont find it appropriate ?

Comment: I am using Bash, and the following lines are written in my .bashrc if [ -f `which powerline-daemon` ]; then
 powerline-daemon -q
 POWERLINE_BASH_CONTINUATION=1
 POWERLINE_BASH_SELECT=1
 . /usr/share/powerline/bash/powerline.sh
fi     I am newbie in linux and all this :-P

Comment: Hmm. For `--width` try adding this immediately before the `powerline-daemon` call: `export COLUMNS=99` (replace 99 with whatever you want).

Comment: I am struggling with this path <python-dir>/site-packages/powerline/config_files/themes/shell/__main__.json. I am unable to find my <python-dir>.

Comment: :-( I ran the find command, no luck. The prompt doesnt show anything.

Comment: Only you know where all the powerline files are on your system since you installed it. If you can't find it then you'll need to read the configuration docs. What about the `--width` setting....using the `export COLUMNS=XX` method I described above?

Comment: i did, it says following. usage: powerline-daemon [-h] [-r MODULE] [-w WIDTH] [--last-exit-code INT]
                        [--last-pipe-status LIST] [--jobnum INT]
                        [-c KEY.KEY=VALUE] [-t THEME.KEY.KEY=VALUE]
                        [-R KEY=VAL] [-p PATH] [--socket ADDRESS]
                        ext [{left,right,above,aboveleft}]
i also tried with -w, same prompt.

Comment: When I said to add that `export` line above the powerline-daemon (or powerline.sh) call that's all you had to do. Don't modify the powerline-daemon/powerline.sh call itself. The `export` replaces the need to add `--width` to anything. I also mention this in my answer in addition to the comment above. I have tried this myself and it works.